# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method SSP::get_field() cannot be called statically

Tags: php, datatables, ssp

I Upgrade php7.4 to php8.2

but i get these error in my SSP Class

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method SSP::get_field() cannot be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\ssp.inc.php:394

My SSP Class

```
<?php

class SSP {

    static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
    {
        $out = array();
        
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $row = array();
            
            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
                $column = $columns[$j];
                $column_name = self::get_column_name($column);
                // Is there a formatter?
                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    $row[$column['dt']] = $column['formatter']($data[$i][$column_name], $data[$i] );
                }
                else {
                    $row[$column['dt']] = $data[$i][$column_name];
                }
            }
            
            $out[] = $row;
        }
        
        return $out;
    }
        
    static function db ( $conn )
    {
        if ( is_array( $conn ) ) {
            return self::sql_connect( $conn );
        }
        
        return $conn;
    }
  
    static function limit ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $limit = '';
        
        if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
            $limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
        }
        
        return $limit;
    }
    
    
    static function order ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $order = '';
        
        if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
            $orderBy = array();
            $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );
            
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];
                
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];
                
                if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                    'ASC' :
                    'DESC';
                    
                    $orderBy[] = '`'.self::get_column_name($column).'` '.$dir;
                }
            }
            
            if ( count( $orderBy ) ) {
                $order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
            }
        }
        
        return $order;
    }
        
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );
        
        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];
            
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];
                
                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "CONVERT(".$column['db']." USING utf8) LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Individual column filtering
        if ( isset( $request['columns'] ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];
                
                $str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];
                
                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
                    $str != '' ) {
                        $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $columnSearch[] = "CONVERT(".$column['db']." USING utf8) LIKE ".$binding;
                    }
            }
        }
        
        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';
        
        if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
            $where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
        }
        
        if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
            $where = $where === '' ?
            implode(' AND ', $columnSearch) :
            $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $columnSearch);
        }
        
        if ( $where !== '' ) {
            $where = 'WHERE '.$where;
        }
        
        return $where;
    }
    
    static function table($in_table)
    {
        if (is_string($in_table)){
            return "`$in_table`";
        }
        $dtables = array();
        foreach ($in_table as $t_info){
            if (!isset($t_info['table'])){
                continue;
            }
            $from_table="";
            if ($t_info['join_type']){
                $from_table.=$t_info['join_type'] . " JOIN ";
            }
            $from_table.= "`".$t_info['table']."`".(($t_info['as']) ? " AS `".$t_info['as']."`" : "");
            if ($t_info['join_on']){
                $from_table.=" ON ".$t_info['join_on'];
            }
            $dtables[] = $from_table." ";
        }
        
        if ( count( $dtables ) ) {
            return implode($dtables);
        }
        
        return "";
    }
           
    function get_field($field, $field_params=null){
        $parts = explode("." , $field);
        for ( $i=0, $len=count($parts) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $parts[$i] = "`$parts[$i]`";
        }
        $fval = implode(".", $parts);
        if ($field_params && $field_params['group_func']){
            $fval = $field_params['group_func']."(".$fval.")";
        }
        return $fval;
    }

    function get_column_name($column){
        if ($column['as']){
            return $column['as'];
        }
        $parts = explode("." , $column['db']);
        if (count($parts) > 1){
            return $parts[1];
        }
        return $parts[0];
    }
    
    static function simple ( $request, $conn, $p_table, $primaryKey, $columns)
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );
        
        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );
        
        //emayskiy: p_table may be array
        $table = self::table($p_table);
        $primaryKey = self::get_field($primaryKey);
        
        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT ".implode(", ", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM $table
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
            );
        
        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT($primaryKey
             FROM  $table
             $where"
            );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];
        
        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT($primaryKey)
             FROM $table"
            );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];
        
        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
            intval( $request['draw'] ) :
            0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }
     
    static function complex ( $request, $conn, $p_table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null, $groupBy=null, $having=null)
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );
        $whereAllSql = '';
                
        //emayskiy: Get field for query
        $primaryKey = self::get_field($primaryKey);
                
        //emayskiy: p_table may be array
        $table = self::table($p_table);
        
        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );
        
        $whereResult = self::_flatten( $whereResult );
        $whereAll = self::_flatten( $whereAll );
        
        if ( $whereResult ) {
            $where = $where ?
            $where .' AND '.$whereResult :
            'WHERE '.$whereResult;
        }
        
        if ( $whereAll ) {
            $where = $where ?
            $where .' AND '.$whereAll :
            'WHERE '.$whereAll;
            
            $whereAllSql = 'WHERE '.$whereAll;
        }
        
        //emayskiy: Add group and having
        $groupBy = ($groupBy) ? ' GROUP BY '.$groupBy .' ' : '';
        $having = ($having) ? ' HAVING '.$having .' ' : '';
        
        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT ".implode(", ", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
             FROM $table
             $where
             $groupBy
             $having
             $order
             $limit"
            );
        
        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT($primaryKey)
             FROM $table
             $where"
            );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];
        
        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT($primaryKey)
             FROM $table ".
            $whereAllSql
            );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];
        

        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
            intval( $request['draw'] ) :
            0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }

    static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
    {
        try {
            $db = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']};port={$sql_details['port']}",
                $sql_details['user'],
                $sql_details['pass'],
                array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
$db->exec("set names utf8");
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
                );
        }
        
        return $db;
    }

    static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
    {
        // Argument shifting
        if ( $sql === null ) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }
        
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
               
        // Bind parameters
        if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $binding = $bindings[$i];
                $stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
            }
        }
        
        // Execute
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
        }
        
        // Return all
        return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
    }
    
    
    static function fatal ( $msg )
    {
        echo json_encode( array(
            "error" => $msg
        ) );
        
        exit(0);
    }

    static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
    {
        $key = ':binding_'.count( $a );
        
        $a[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'val' => $val,
            'type' => $type
        );
        
        return $key;
    }
   
    static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
    {
        $out = array();
        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $out[] = (($prop=='db')? self::get_field($a[$i][$prop], $a[$i]).(($a[$i]['as']) ? " AS `".$a[$i]['as']."`" : ""):$a[$i][$prop]);
        }
        
        return $out;
    }
    static function _flatten ( $a, $join = ' AND ' )
    {
        if ( ! $a ) {
            return '';
        }
        else if ( $a && is_array($a) ) {
            return implode( $join, $a );
        }
        return $a;
    }
}
```

What's wrong ? any why when update it's stopped
Please Very Important to fixing it

Upgrade from php7.4 to php8.2

Answer (score -1):

You can safely change `function get_field` to `static function get_field` to fix the problem. Almost every function is `SSP` is already static and `get_field` doesn't use `$this` or reference any class variables, so it can be made static like everything else in the class. Same with the `get_column_name` function.

Newer PHP versions started enforcing more strict rules with regards to calling a non-static method (e.g. `function foo`) statically (e.g. `$object::foo()`). Before, this would be allowed even though it was being called in a different way than it was defined.

For more information, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php.

Comment: after change to static function get_field i get a new error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "radius" in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\list_users.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\ssp.inc.php(47): {closure}('ssas, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\ssp.inc.php(461): SSP::data_output(Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\list_users.php(75): SSP::complex(Array, Array, Array, '`username`', Array, '', 'mt.owner != 'ca...', '', '') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\list_users.php on line 29